# Prove that $\mathbb{R^3}$ is not a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider $\mathbb{R^3}$ with the usual addition $+$ of vectors, but with scalar multiplication $\otimes$ defined by:

$k$ $\otimes$ $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$ = $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ ky \\ 2kz \end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix}$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R^3}.$

Show that $\mathbb{R^3}$ together with the operations + and $\otimes$ is not a vector space.

My attempt:

A property of a vector space is $(-1)$ $\otimes$ $\mathbf{u}$ = $\mathbf{-u}$

So, applying this would result to:

$(-1)$ $\otimes$ $(x, y, z)$ = $(x, -y, -2z)$.

To fulfill the property, this must be equal to $\mathbf{-u}$.

So, $(x, -y, -2z)$ = $-(x, y, z)$ = $(-x, -y, -z)$.

But, $(x, -y, -2z)$ $\ne$ $(-x, -y, -z)$ for all $x$.

Hence, it is not a vector space.

Is my attempt enough to prove it isn't a vector space? Or at least, correct? Should I show further proof?

Comment: If... *if* ...you already know that in *any* vector spacve it must be true that $\;(-1)\cdot v=-v\;$  and also that in your case $\;-(x,y,z)=(-x,y,-z)\;$ ,then yes: it is enough....

Answer (score 5):

An idea to simplify things: it's easy to show that in any vector space if must be that $\;1\cdot v= v\;$, for any (supposed) vector $\;v\;$ , but here

$$1\cdot\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}:=\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\2z\end{pmatrix}\neq\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$

and thus we're done.

Comment: We are assuming here that that the multiplicative invariant for $\otimes$ is $e=1$, shouldn't we have to prove instead there is no such $e$ ?

Comment: @zwim The multiplicative unit of the base field hasn't changed: it is $\;1\;$, the real number one.